# Vue Js component wont display in Blade view Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

My Blade View 'chat.blade.php'

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"</div>

                <div class="panel-body">Chats
                    <chat-messages :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <chat-form
                        v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                        :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"
                    ></chat-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This code is extend from app.blade.php, which probably its not really the main focus of the problem

and here is My 2 Component From My Vue JS
'ChatMessages.vue'

```
<template>
<ul class="chat">
    <li class="left clearfix" v-for="message in messages">
        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">
                    {{ message.user.name }}
                </strong>
            </div>
            <p>
                {{ message.message }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
     props: ['messages']
  };
  </script>
```

and here is the 'ChatForm.vue'

```
<template>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="newMessage" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">
    
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendMessage">
            Send
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
  </template>

   <script>
     export default {
     props: ['user'],

     data() {
        return {
            newMessage: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            this.$emit('messagesent', {
                user: this.user,
                message: this.newMessage
            });

            this.newMessage = ''
        }
    }    
}
       </script>
```

and here is the following screenshot of the problem
[Click here for the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjnjp.png)

as you can see in the screenshot, the chat component from vue.js listed below, wont show up, its just appear blank, only displaying scrollbar,navbar and 'Chats' text. which is came from app.blade.php]
Please help me :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not commit any messages to your component. `:messages="messages"` is Vue syntax.

Assuming your controller assigns `$messages` to your view:

```
<chat-messages messages="{{ json_encode($messages) }}"></chat-messages>
```

should do it. You need to use blade variables to assign

Comment: Its Also applies to chat-form as well? And also still dont get it what is blade variables that u mean. Sorry im still new.

Comment: its still not solved, please i need more detailed explanation